# Python urwid module- AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'render

Tags: python, urwid

I'm new to urwid's console widgets in Python and trying to learn it. For experimenting, I am trying to make a screen where the title "Foobar" is on top and on the bottom I would have a 2 graphs in a left column(I believe this would be called the body).

So far I tried this:

```
class SwitchingPadding(urwid.Padding):
    def padding_values(self, size, focus):
        maxcol = size[0]
        width, ignore = self.original_widget.pack(size, focus=focus)
        if maxcol > width:
            self.align = "left"
        else:
            self.align = "right"
        return urwid.Padding.padding_values(self, size, focus)

class Graphics():
    palette = [
        ('body',         'black',      'light gray', 'standout'),
        ('header',       'white',      'dark red',   'bold'),
        ('button normal','light gray', 'dark blue', 'standout'),
        ('button select','white',      'dark green'),
        ('button disabled','dark gray','dark blue'),
        ('edit',         'light gray', 'dark blue'),
        ('title',      'white',      'black'),
        ('chars',        'light gray', 'black'),
        ('exit',         'white',      'dark cyan'),
        ('bg background','light gray', 'black'),
        ('bg 1',         'black',      'dark blue', 'standout'),
        ('bg 1 smooth',  'dark blue',  'black'),
        ('bg 2',         'black',      'dark cyan', 'standout'),
        ('bg 2 smooth',  'dark cyan',  'black'),
        ]
    graph_num_bars = 2
    graph_samples_per_bar = 10

    def update_graph(self, force_update=False):
        o = self.get_offset_now()
        if o == self.last_offset and not force_update:
            return False
        self.last_offset = o
        gspb = self.graph_samples_per_bar
        r = gspb * self.graph_num_bars
        d, max_value, repeat = self.controller.get_data( o, r )
        l = []
        for n in range(self.graph_num_bars):
            value = sum(d[n*gspb:(n+1)*gspb])/gspb
            # toggle between two bar types
            if n & 1:
                l.append([0,value])
            else:
                l.append([value,0])
        self.graph.set_data(l,max_value)


    def setup(self):
    #Create Title for Frame widget
    self.title = urwid.BigText("Foobar", "Thin6x6Font")
    bt = SwitchingPadding(self.title, 'left', None) 
    bt = urwid.AttrWrap(bt, 'title')
    bt = urwid.Filler(bt, 'bottom', None, 7)
    bt = urwid.BoxAdapter(bt, 7)

    def bar_graph(self):
    satt = None
    w = urwid.BarGraph(['bg background','bg 1','bg 2'], satt=satt)
    return w

    def main_window(self): 
        self.graph = self.bar_graph()
        self.graph_wrap = urwid.WidgetWrap( self.graph )
        vline = urwid.AttrWrap( urwid.SolidFill(u'\u2502'), 'line')
        c = self.graph_controls()
        w = urwid.Columns([('weight',2,self.graph_wrap),
            ('fixed',1,vline), c],
            dividechars=1, focus_column=2)
        w = urwid.Padding(w,('fixed left',1),('fixed right',0))
        w = urwid.AttrWrap(w,'body')
        w = urwid.LineBox(w)
        w = urwid.AttrWrap(w,'line')
        w = self.main_shadow(w)
        return w

    def main(self):
        self.view = self.setup()
        self.loop = urwid.MainLoop(self.view, self.palette)
        self.loop.run()


def main():
        Graphics().main()

if '__main__'==__name__:
    main()
```

But I stuck where I am getting:

```
one@development ~/try $ python foo.py 

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "foo.py", line 92, in <module>
        main()
      File "foo.py", line 89, in main
        Graphics().main()
      File "foo.py", line 85, in main
        self.loop.run()
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 272, in run
        self.screen.run_wrapper(self._run)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/urwid/raw_display.py", line 242, in run_wrapper
        return fn()
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 312, in _run
        self.draw_screen()
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/urwid/main_loop.py", line 563, in draw_screen
        canvas = self._topmost_widget.render(self.screen_size, focus=True)
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'render'
    one@development ~/try $
```

Anyone have know why?

Comment: Judging from the traceback, the error didn't came from this script.

Comment: It was from this script. But I figured it out.... I wasn't passing the widget(w) and it was complaining.

Answer (score 1):

self._topmost_widget is None.  Check where it is created or updated.